# Not Contains TestCase filter not working in VSTest 16.6.1

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

According to the [official TestCase documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md), you can use a "not contains" (!~) filter in a TestCase filter.

I'm trying to use this filter in an Azure Devops pipeline, but the filter is not supported according to the error I get when running that pipeline:

```
##[error]Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Error: Invalid Condition 'FullyQualifiedName!~DSN'. Specify the correct format and try again. Note that the incorrect format can lead to no test getting executed.
```

[This functionality was added in a 16.0 preview version](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/releases.md#1600-preview-20181128-01).
The pipeline is using VSTest 16.6.1, as evidenced by thes lines in the output:

```
C:\agent\_work\_tool\VsTest\16.6.1\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@C:\agent\_work\_temp\xulnpcmgdnx.tmp"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.6.1
```

However, the "not contains" operator is still not supported.

I have tried:

1. Using a preview version of VSTest (16.7)
2. Using "Visual Studio 2019" as test platform version in my VsTest pipeline task (as opposed to directly using a VSTest version)
3. Using a VSTest version prior to the release that included the "not contains" test filter, which showed the exact same error as expected

I'm at a loss, is there some other kind of dependency that I'm not aware about? Could this be an issue / bug on Microsoft's part? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi friend, not getting your latest information about this issue. Does it still persists to block you, feel free to let me know if there's any update. I'm willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

### Update the MS Test NuGet Packages

I got error, `Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Error: Invalid Condition 'FullyQualifiedName!~Integration'.` on my build server.

My code was using a version 1 of MS Test and .NET 7.  Update your MS Test nuget packages in your tests project.

Right click the project and select **Manage NuGet Packages...**

[image]

Now my build and test works!

I have experienced this before as well.  Older MS Test is missing features like this and `[DataRow]`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to the VSTest version you use. Here're some tests on my side:

- Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.1(Hosted VS2017 agent,Failed):

[image]

- Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.6.0(Hosted Windows2019,Succeeded):

[image]

- Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.7.0-preview-20200519-01(Self-agent,Succeeded)

[image]

[image]

So i suggest you can run the pipeline with windows 2019 agent first to check if the issue comes from VSTest versions. Then choose correct version.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're getting at - I showed that I'm running VSTest 16.6.1. The "not contains" operator was added in a 16.0 preview.

Comment: @JoshuaVdM Please check my pics above, it works well for 16.0.0 and 16.7.0-preview-20200519-01 in my machine. It proves that the operator was actually added in 16.0. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with 16.6.1, can you run the test with Micirosoft-hosted agent to test that? The hosted agent has 16.6.0, let's check if the issue is about the 16.6.1 you use.

Comment: I see what you mean now - I'll try with a microsoft-hosted machine with VS2019 to be sure!